# grep a range of N to N tokens

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I would like to grep (I can accept non-grep answers but it is what I am most used to for this) lines which have a range of tokens delimited by a whitespace and with the ability to ignore punctuation marks. This means that if I want three to five tokens I would get lines with three, four or fives tokens but not one, two, six or twenty tokens. I have periods at the end and sometimes commas in the middle which I things I would like to account for if possible.  Also the real data is actually words so I would like an answer with clear instructions for allowing characters which are not necessarily a-zA-Z, for example the word "can't".

My data is like this:

```
aa .
aa bb'b , c ddd e f gg .
aa bb .
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aa bb'b cc dd e f .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```

I tried this:

```
grep -e "[a-zA-Z']* ,*\{3,5\}"
```

What I expected to get was this:

```
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -E "^([a-zA-Z']+ *,* ){3,5}\.$" file
```

Output:

```
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```

Comment: I am going to accept this because it is closest to the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can make this task simple, because it has a variable `NF` that counts number of fields (separated by blanks) in each line, so:

```
awk 'NF >= 4 && NF <= 6' infile
```

I incremented its value to take into account last period. It yields:

```
a b c d e .
a b c d .
a b c .
```

---

**EDIT**: To ignore commas, use the `FS` variable (Field Separator) with a regular expression:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[[:blank:],]+" } NF >= 4 && NF <= 6' infile
```

It yields:

```
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```

Comment: Thanks Birei.  This is pretty close and I can work with this.  Sometimes I have some commas that I would like to ignore which is why i was looking for something closer to a regex to make it easier to edit.

Comment: @badner: Also `awk` can use a regular expression to select how to split the line into fields, but the best option is to edit your question with some sample data that take into account all (or most) of possiblities. Perhaps `a`, `b` or `c` are not enough.

Comment: I can edit it, my goal was to keep it clean and simple.  I can also allow for non-grep answers

Comment: Yes. Simple but also complete. Your sample data has no commas. For `awk`, it's different `a, b, c,` that `a , b , c`, so the aproach would be different. And much more complex if your data has both versions mixed, so if you don't provide some input data that reflect those cases, it's difficult for any answer to provide an accurate solution.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice.  I updated by answer to account for commas and apostrophes. I am still a newbie here so thank you for your patience. My goal is to be able to edit it in case another exception occurs.  sometimes grep and awk answers get pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed example to add to the mix:

```
sed -n "/^\([a-zA-Z',]* \)\{3,5\}\.$/p"
```

**Output:**

```
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
awk '/aaa+/' file
aaa bb'b cccc dddd e .
aaaa bb'b cccc , dddd .
aaaaa bb'b c .
```